# How to randomly delete 10% attributes values from df in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a example dataset. It has 2000 rows and 15 columns. Last columns will be need as decision class in classification.

I need to delete randomly 10% of attributes values. So 10% values from columns `0-13` should be `NA`.

I wrote a for loop. It randomizes a `colNumber` (`0-13`) and `rowNumber` (`0-2000`) and it replaces a value to `NA`. But I think (and I see this) it's not a faster solution. I tried to find something else in `pandas`, not core python, but couldn't find anything.

Maybe someone have better idea? More `pandas` solution? Or maybe something completely different?

Comment: Are you trying to delete possibly different attributes for each row?

Comment: No, just randomly pick col and row. And counter. If in some random is already NA, counter didn't increment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make use of `pandas`' `sample` method.

#### Imports and set up data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 100
data = {
    'a': np.random.random(size=n),
    'b': np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), size=n),
    'c': np.random.random(size=n),
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Solution

```
for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[df.sample(frac=0.1).index, col] = np.nan
```

#### Solution without for loop:

```
def delete_10(col):
    col.loc[col.sample(frac=0.1).index] = np.nan
    return col

df.apply(delete_10, axis=0)
```

#### Check

Check to see proportion of `NaN` values:

```
df.isnull().sum() / len(df)
```

Output:

```
a    0.1
b    0.1
c    0.1
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Great solution, I didn't think about sample! +1

Comment: @BrunoMello thanks!  It's easy to forget specific methods given how big `pandas` is.

Comment: Thank U for answer! I will try to read more about that method :) Now I have something wrong coz It's not deleting 10% of all values but 10% of whole rows. Coz now I have a 200 full of None rows :D But i try to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, you're right!  My answer is incorrect, it does delete entire rows.  Apologies.  I'll have another look.

Comment: @Chris I think you can sample in every column with a for, that way it won't get always the same rows

Comment: Thanks for the edit @BrunoMello, that did the trick.  Never a fan of for loops for dataframes but at least it works now.

Comment: You can use apply too @Chris

Comment: Thanks @BrunoMello, I appreciate your edits/improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this work, create a random array and see if is less than 0.1:

```
mask = np.random.random(df.iloc[:, :13].shape)<0.1
mask[13:] = False
df[mask] = np.nan
```

Comment: Thanks for answes. But I notice it's deleting in my case only some values with first 20 rows and I don't know why

Comment: @martin It's a probabilistic method, it will not always get exactly what you expect